# How to move an object created in SceneKit from one point to another

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a cube that I created using Scenekit for ios. I want the cube to move from one point to another. How can I do that? I read the Apple documentation on the runAction method. But I do not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To run an action on an object, you have to create the action first. For moving an object around the scene, create an action like this:

```
let moveTo = SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(1, 1, 1), duration: 1)
```

This will move the object you run the action on to the point `1, 1, 1`.

If you would rather move the object *by* some value, you can do that the following way:

```
let moveBy = SCNAction.moveByX(0, y: 1, z: 0, duration: 1)
```

Then, simply run the action on the object you want to move:

```
myObject.runAction(moveBy)
```

You can of course make this shorter and instead of creating a variable for the action, create the action right within `.runAction()`, but it makes it easier to read sometimes.

Hope that helps :)